# node.js cannot find module "mongodb"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect my node js file to mongodb but I keep running into this error. mongodb is in the node_modules file. I'm unsure of what Im doing wrong

```
node mongstuff.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/mohammed/node_modules/mongstuff.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Comment: From which directory are you running the command in?

Comment: can you post the contents of mongstuff.js?

Comment: I guess you run the command in `node_modules`. If it's correct, please run it on the project directory.